# Linux FTP User Directory Access Restriction?

Tags: linux, ftp, sftp

I'm setting up the SFTP with different users. I simply need to strict some users to be given stricted Folder Access.

- General users to access the whole Main FTP Directory normally: `/project/workarea/*`
- User `X` to be able to access **only**: `/project/workarea/room-x/*`
- So the User `X` should not be able to access other FTP directories above.

**The problem is about `X` User only**. (Folder Restriction Issue)
How to configure it please?

Comment: Should the general users only have access to the Main FTP Directory, or do they have access to other directories as well?  Should user X have access to any other directories outside of the /project directory?

Comment: Hi Paul, as i stated clearly above, general users will access `/project/workarea/*` and only `X` user will access only `/project/workarea/room-x/*` (only `room-x` folder and below. Not above). (Please mind the asterisks `*` also.) Just only to consider the issue with `X` user. (No need to consider about general users and their permissions, whatever they have. You can ignore.)

Answer (score 1):

This is the process for constraining users to specific folders over sftp.

The first step is to use the internal sftp service within sshd, by editing `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`. Change it so it looks like this:

```
# Subsystem       sftp    /usr/lib/misc/sftp-server
Subsystem       sftp    internal-sftp
```

At the end, add the following, which will constrain users of the 'sftpusers' group to their home folder only:

```
 Match Group sftpusers
   ChrootDirectory %h
   ForceCommand internal-sftp
   AllowTcpForwarding no
```

`%h` represents their home directory.

Add user `x` to the `sftpusers` group:

```
 useradd -G sftpusers x
```

Now edit `/etc/passwd` for user `x` so that their home directory is the folder they are allowed to access and also change their shell to `nologin` to prevent shell access:

```
x:x:1000:1000::/project/workarea/room-x/:/sbin/nologin
```